# Why will my git not push to my github account?

Tags: git, github

I created a github repository and then went into my local on my computer and did `git init` I thought I did everything right but now when I push I get an error. I am not sure how else to link my git local with my github.

I have checked with `git config -l` and everything looks correct.

```
fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: Can you share what is the command which you run to `push`?

Comment: fatal: 'master' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: Not the result from the command. The actual command which you ran.

Comment: Did you set a remote? Why did you use `git init` to create a new repository and not just `git clone` to clone your github repository to your local machine?

Comment: `git push`  was the actual command but it also happens when I do `git push origin master`

Comment: I did `git init` because the files were already on my computer and I wanted to get them into github. Should I not have done that?

Comment: You need to add the remote toward the github repository.

Comment: It says the remote already exists

Comment: *I did `git init` because the files were already on my computer* That's fine, but until you configure a remote git has no way to know **where** to push the commits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the Github repository as a remote on the local repo.

```
git remote add origin "Your remote repository url"
```

**Edit**
If the remote origin already exists, try:

```
git remote set-url origin "Your remote repository url"
```

Comment: When I do that it just responds `fatal: remote origin already exists.`

Comment: Ok. Then try this:
git remote set-url origin "Your remote repository url"

Comment: Ok, I did what you said to do. Now `git push` ?

Comment: git push -u origin master

Comment: `! [rejected]        master -> master (fetch first)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/KPH3082/WeatherPy_WashU.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.`

Comment: Ok. Then try. First do
git pull origin master
Afterwards
git push origin master